# Vue - Passing data from child to parent - Basic emit not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a basic Vue2 component and I am trying to pass data from the child to the parent component using `$emit`. **Note,** my-component contains a table where when I click on a row, onRowClick fires successfully, outputting 'foobar' to the console. For some reason, I'm not able to get the parent method to fire on $emit and success isn't being logged to console. Any idea why this is?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent.vue";

window.onload = function () {
   var main = new Vue({
      el: '#app-v2',
      components: { MyComponent },
      methods: {
         onCouponApplied(data) {
            console.log("Success, coupon applied, " + data);
            this.saying = "Sunglasses are " + data; //Sunglasses are cool
         }
      },
      data: {
         contactEditPage: {
            saying: ""
         }
      }
   });
}
```

MyComponent.vue

```
export default {
        methods: {
            onRowClick(event){ 
               this.$emit('applied', 'Cool');
               console.log("foobar");
            }
```

HTML

```
<div id="app-v2">
    <my-component @applied="onCouponApplied"></my-component>
     {{ saying }} //trying to output: sunglasses are cool
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe `$emit` couldn't able to find parent components. Try removing `window.onload` wrapper from your code...

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, here's a Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/yldNSHD5S55VykT2FrRn?p=preview) with enough fragments of your code to get going. The problem must lie outside what you've posted, as the example appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I fixed this issue by using $root.

For example in parent Vue component

```
mounted(){
    this.$root.$on('event-name',function(value){
        // code
    });
},
```

And child component should be like this:

```
this.$root.$emit('event-name',[data]);
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: thank you, in a hundred times better and easier, than many decisions here

Comment: you can use VueX for alternate solution. I think it's fine to use this approach also.